# exec.Command hangs on Bash script containing nohup

Tags: bash, go

When I use Go's `exec.Command{}` to execute some bash script that contains nohup, it will hang forever.

I don't know what are the differences between ping and ifconfig. I tried to redirect the stdin (`< /dev/null`), the stdout(`> /dev/null`) and the stderr(`2> /dev/null`), and their combination, some of them work some don't.

When I use `sh` to execute the script, it just ends up immediately.

The Go code:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os/exec"
)

func main() {
    cmd := exec.Command("sh", "a.sh")
    out, err := cmd.Output() // Or cmd.CombinedOutput()
    fmt.Println(string(out), err)
}
```

The Bash script (a.sh):

```sh
#!/bin/bash

# hangs
#nohup ping localhost &

# dot not hang
nohup ifconfig &
```

Comment: Is this better? `nohup ping localhost >/dev/null 2>&1`

Comment: @Cyrus Nope, It also hangs.

Comment: @torek Thanks. If  ping never stops printing.  I think `sh a.sh` should not exit. But it ends up immediately and prints `nohup: appending output to 'nohup.out'`.

Comment: @torek Thanks for the very detailed explanation of how redirections work. Now I may think that what prevents cmd from returning(exiting) is whether there's a program has write access to the output pipe cmd passed to, no matter what it writes. To verify this, I wrote another one line of code that just doing the `time.Sleep(...)`, cmd still doesn't return. `nohup ping ... >/dev/null 2>&1 &` works, but now their (nohup's and ping's) outputs are all gone because of redirection. The nohup.out file is gone. Kind of annoying thing.

Comment: I turned the comments into an answer, so I'll remove the comments now...

Answer (score 3):

(Converting comments, with glitches fixed, to answer)

The use of `nohup` here is mostly a [red herring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_herring).  The real problem is that `ping` never finishes.  However, `nohup` has some extra weirdness, which you can see if you run, from an interactive terminal, these two sets of commands:

```
$ nohup echo foo
nohup: ignoring input and appending output to 'nohup.out'
$ cat nohup.out
foo
$
```

vs:

```
$ nohup echo foo </dev/null 2>&1 | cat 
foo
$
```

Note how the first one printed a weird message, and then the output `foo` went to a file; the second did not, and then the output `foo` showed up on the regular output stream.  This is because POSIX says that `nohup` should do these redirections if appropriate.<sup>1</sup>  When run with `exec.Cmd` and `cmd.Output`, the redirections are *not* performed.

At the OS level, on a Linux- or other Unix-like system, the `exec` code creates an [OS `pipe` object](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/pipe.2.html) by which the invoked command can send output back to the Go runtime.  (There may be a separate pipe for its stderr output, or the two may both be directed to a single pipe, depending on how you run the command; see https://golang.org/src/os/exec/exec.go#L280.)  This pipe winds up being passed to `ping`, so that `ping` can keep writing output there as long as it likes.

The *shell itself* exits, because the command `nohup ping localhost &` is backgrounded.  However, `ping` still has write access to the pipe object, so the Go runtime continues calling the OS `read` code until the pipe is closed—which is never.  If the pipe were ever closed, the Go runtime would receive EOF and call the `wait` system call to collect the shell's exit status, but that never happens.

Redirecting `ping`'s output, such that the shell itself has the only write access to the pipe, should result in the pipe being closed as soon as the shell itself exits.

(Some shells may have a builtin `nohup` that may behave weirdly, especially in the presence of redirection.  This is true of some particularly ancient shells.)

---

<sup>1</sup>See https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/nohup.html for complete details.  The Linux variant redirects stdin as well as stdout and stderr, if the input is a terminal, and if the output and stderr are terminals.  The FreeBSD variant redirects only stdout and/or stderr.  The "is a terminal" test is based on the C language `isatty` function, which does the same thing as https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/crypto/ssh/terminal#IsTerminal.

Comment: Before now, I think `exec.Cmd` just waits for the exit of the command being executed. `ping still has write access to the pipe object, so the Go runtime continues calling the OS read code until the pipe is closed—which is never.` changes my point of view. I will take a deep look at the source code of package `exec`. Thanks again.